# How to make TypeORM save values of CreateDateColumn, UpdateDateColumn in UTC?

Tags: typeorm

The columns use current timestamp. How do I make it UTC?

```
    @CreateDateColumn({
        type: 'timestamptz',
        name: 'create_date'
    })
    private createDate: Moment;

    @UpdateDateColumn({
        type: 'timestamptz',
        name: 'update_date',
    })
    private updateDate: Moment;
```

Answer (score 1):

You have some options.

1 - Create the columns directly from postgres query:

```
create temporary table test(
    id int, 
    create_date timestamp without time zone default (now() at time zone 'utc')
);
```

2 - Convert to UTC in application and create the column with `{ type: 'timestamptz' }`

You can take a look at [this link](https://bleepcoder.com/typeorm/475111829/timestamp-and-postgresql) and check if one of the solutions solves your problem.